# Index Error while webscraping news websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to web-scrape the titles of news articles, but I encounter an "Index Error" when the following code. I'm facing a problem only in the last line of code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL= 'https://www.ndtv.com/coronavirus?pfrom=home-mainnavgation'
r1 = requests.get(URL)
coverpage = r1.content
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('h3', class_='item-title')
coverpage_news[4].get_text()
```

This is the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f7f1f6fab81c> in <module>
      6 soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
      7 coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('h3', class_='item-title')
----> 8 coverpage_news[4].get_text()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That means are aren't 5 elements on the page that satisfy the criteria you're searching for.

Comment: I don't see any `<h3 class="item-title">` on that page.

Comment: I see `<h3 class="dr-advice_title">`, is that what you're looking for? I also see lots of `<a ... class="item-title">`

Comment: There's also `<h3 class="list-txt">`, they contain `<a class="item-title">`

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: I want to extract all the titles with the h3 tag and with the class "item-title" in that website

Comment: But there are no titles with the `h3` tag and the class `item-title`. Use `View Source` to see the HTML. Paste an example of the HTML you want to extract into the question.

Comment: the class="item-title" is within the <a> tag as you rightly mentioned above

Comment: That's not the same thing. Your code looks for he class on the `h3` element itself, not an element contained within it.

Comment: <a href="https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/coronavirus-indias-covid-19-cases-at-80-88-lakh-with-48-648-fresh-cases-2-4-lower-than-yesterday-1-21-090-total-deaths-2317886?pfrom=home-coronavirus-topscroll_live"** class="item-title"**>India's Covid Tally at 80.88 Lakh; 48,648 New Cases, 563 Deaths In A Day</a>

Comment: should i put 'a' instead of 'h3' in the code?

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `soup1.select()` to search for nested elements matching a CSS selector:

```
coverpage_news = soup1.select("h3 a.item-title")
```

This will find an `a` element with `class="item-title"` that's a descendant of an `h3` element.

Comment: this code is giving me only one result, but i want to scrape the entire titles of the webpage

Comment: It should find all matches. `select_one()` returns just the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('h3', class_='item-title')
```

to

```
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('h3', class_='list-txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing @Barmar's helpful answer a little bit to show all titles:

```
coverpage_news = soup1.select("h3 a.item-title")
for link in coverpage_news:
  print(link.text)
```

Output:

```
US Covid Infections Cross 9 Million, Record 1-Day Spike Of 94,000 Cases
Johnson & Johnson Plans To Test COVID-19 Vaccine On Youngsters Soon
Global Stock Markets Decline As Coronavirus Infection Rate Weighs
Cristiano Ronaldo Recovers From Coronavirus
Reliance's July-September Profit Falls 15% As Covid Slams Oil Business
"Likely To Know By December If We'll Have Covid Vaccine": Top US Expert
With No Local Case In A Record 200 Days, This Country Is World's Envy
Delhi Blames Pollution For Covid Spike At High-Level Health Ministry Meet
Delhi Covid Cases Above 5,000 For 3rd Straight Day, Spike In ICU Patients
2 Million Indians Returned From Abroad Under Vande Bharat Mission: Centre
Existing Lockdown Restrictions Extended In Maharashtra Till November 30
Can TB Vaccine Protect Elderly From Covid?
Is The Covid-19 Situation Worsening In Delhi?
What's The Truth Behind India's Falling Covid Numbers?
"Slight Laxity Can Lead To Spike": AIIMS Director As India Sees Drop In Covid Cases
```